# How can I filter a line pattern with sed?

Tags: unix, sed

Suppose I have a shell script, `foo.sh`, that produces repeating sets of data like this:

```
<name 1>
<address 1>
<mother's name 1>
<pet's name 1>
<comment 1>
<name 2>
<address 2>
<mother's name 2>
<pet's name 2>
<comment 2>
...
```

I want to extract the 1st and 3rd lines from each 5-line block, so the modified output looks like this:

```
<name 1>
<mother's name 1>
<name 2>
<mother's name 2>
...
```

The catch being that there's no pattern unique to these lines, so I need to filter by line numbers specifically. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU sed:

```
sed -n '1~5p;3~5p' file.txt
```

From GNU sed manual:

```
first~step
    Match every step'th line starting with line first. For example, ``sed -n 1~2p''
    will print all the odd-numbered lines in the input stream, and the address 2~5
    will match every fifth line, starting with the second. first can be zero; in
    this case, sed operates as if it were equal to step.  (This is an extension.)
```

Comment: A short explanation on what this line does (what do the magic numbers and the argument mean) will be very benificial

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a `sed` expert, but you can do this in Awk:

```
$ awk '(i==0 || i==2) { print }
                      { i = (i+1) % 5 }
  ' < filename.txt
```

Or, in one line

```
$ awk '(NR%5==1 || NR%5==3)' < filename.txt
```

Comment: +1 for the second example. Note that it's not necessary to use redirection. AWK accepts filenames as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `awk`?

```
awk 'NR % 5 == 1 || NR % 5 == 3' foofile
```

So basically what's happening is

- awk opens foofile.
- it reads through it line by line
- the line number is divided by five and if the remainder is 1 or 3 (i.e. the first or the third line in a block of 5) then it prints that line

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n 'h;n;n;H;n;n;g;p' file
```